# Does the Existence of ACID transactions invalidate the CAP theorem?

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed-system, acid, cap-theorem

If there is a database system that can handle both ACID transactions and non ACID transactions, would that invalidate the CAP theorem which states that you have to make a trade off between A (availability) and C(consistency) in the presence of partitions

Comment: As per CAP, you don't have to tradeoff between 'C' and 'A' if you are ready to give up on 'P' (partition tolerance).

Comment: @A.B In this I assume there are partitions- edited the question